# What does ^+Z do to a process

Tags: process

In command line I wrote:

```
michael@ubuntu:~$ firefox
```

Firefox launched. Command prompt ($) disappeared.

Then I pressed ^+z.

The result was:

```
[1]+  Stopped                 firefox
```

Well, Firefox really stopped. It did not react anyhow. So, I could not close it by pressing the cross of the window. By the way, the menu items 'Tools', and 'Help' somehow showed some signs of life. They showed drop-down lists, but nothing more (no reaction to inner menu items).

Well, I could not end Firefox through System Monitor.

Could you comment on this case: what happened after pressing ^+z?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By pressing ^z ( <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> ) you send a `SIGSTOP` signal to the process, which stops it. You can re-start it using the `fg` command (foreground) or make it continue to run in the background using the `bg` command.

Comment: Ctrl + Z suspends the process, in other words.